# HTTP Response in angular typescript observable loads very slow

Tags: angular, typescript, http, httpresponse

Sorry if this has already been asked, but, surprisingly, I couldn't find anyone with this question.

I have an Angular CLI project using Angular 4 and observables to get an http request. The problem is that as more data is stored, the larger the request gets. So now it's REALLY slow, like unbearably slow. Anyways, here's a snippet of my code where I'm requesting some info in an observable, then rendering a datatable when it's complete.

Question: How can I have the table render when there's 10 or so values in but not all of them or have the table load faster for the user while still getting data from the backend?

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

export class TestcasesComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.httpClient.get("/api/test-case")
    .subscribe(cases => {
      this.cases = cases; <-- this takes awhile
      renderTable(this.trigger);
      this.loading = false;
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: You're confusing request and response. How many rows are you loading? Why don't you paginate the results?

Comment: Ahh, by bad. A couple thousand. I am. Only the first ten show at first, but that doesn't stop the response from getting all the thousands

Comment: Well, change that. Change your backend service to only return a page of data, and get the next page when navigating to it, instead of loading everything eagerly.

Comment: So you're saying there's no way I can handle this on the frontend or from the call?

Comment: Loading thousands of rows from your database, sending them over the network and parsing them obviously takes a lot of time, and is a huge waste since the goal is to display 10 rows. Do the right (and easiest) thing, and paginate your data.

Comment: If the server wants to send you 10,000 records, and doing so causes a performance penalty, you have to change the server so it stops sending so many records.

Comment: Please try using this to diagnose what is causing the issue. The 10,000 records shouldn't be a problem to load, therefore the rendering of each record is the issue. I agree with the notion of only rendering 10 records at a time as opposed to 10,000. 

Details of how to run the audit are here: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/rendering-tools/

Comment: I am only rendering 10 at a time, so once the response is back, it renders fairly quickly. I will take a look at this tool (thanks btw) but I'm pretty sure it's the loading

Comment: Wow, I've discovered a whole other issue. I've been doing many more requests than I thought and I'm guess that's my problem. Thanks everyone. Will update again once I get this fixed

Comment: Glad to hear you've made some progress on this.